# How to use a transparent material with mist in Blender Internal?

Tags: rendering, texturing

I have a leaf material that I want to use in the mist. (Blender Internal renderer) when choosing Z Transparency, the result looks incorrect. Look at the tree in the center, all the leaves looks too vivid compared to the correctly faded bark.

[image]

When I changed it to Raytrace, the mist occlusion of the tree at center looks correct, but the transparent part around the texture has a color which is pre-mist.

Actually, the mist seems to be in effect as when I turn off the mist the color became more vivid, but it looks like the mist **behind** them has no effect. (So leaves in the front of camera looks more bugged as more mist is behind them)

[image]

The leaf material consist of an image that affects color and another image that affects alpha.

[image]

More images to help debugging. In Z Transparency the part where leaves overlap looks more vivid.

[image]

In Raytrace, the part where leaves overlap is OK, but the transparent part around them uses only mist in front of them. It should not use any mist and became see through to be correct.

[image]

This is the scene without mist.

[image]

Another observation with Z Transparency, I use the viewer to view a mist pass. When I have Use Mist off the overlapping leaves does not get transparent.

[image]

But with Use Mist, it somehow adds strange transparency where they overlap.

[image]

And the scene does not use any AO, Indirect Lighting, or Environment Lighting. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up turning off all the "Use Mist", use Z Transparency where the mist pass image looks correct, and then use that to create my own mist with a compositor instead. It's OK now, plus I can process the mist to color differently.

[image]